# Reading a value from an outside function for a Cypress test run

Tags: javascript, function, cypress

In a cypress test run I want to get a value in my fileWithTest.js from an outside function from the fileWithObjects.js.

Besides some having different error messages before I made it that the test runs completely without error messages ... but with this remark: [object Undefined]

The test part of this example code is:
a login,
navigation to a page,
reading a value from a specific table cell, (with a funtion that is in a different file)
changing page,
type the before read value into an input field

This is the part with the "outside function":

fileWithObjects.js

```
    functionForSpecificTableCell_Month2() {
        var specificValueFromTableCell_Month2 = ''
        cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.tabele_row3 > td:nth-child(1)').each(($e1, index, $list) => {
            var titletext=$e1.text()
            
            if(titletext.includes('A Specific Headline')) {
                cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(3)').eq(index).then(function(amount) {
                    var specificValueFromTableCell_Month2 = amount.text()
                    return specificValueFromTableCell_Month2.trim()
                })
            } 
            
        })
        return specificValueFromTableCell_Month2
}
```

This is the test file that uses the "outside function":

fileWithTest.js

```
    describe('Test Read From Outside Function', ()=> {

    it.only('Read a value from a function that has got to be included', () => {

        cy.wait(500)
        cy.openHomePage()

        // Login
        cy.fixture('role').then(roledata => {
            const username = roledata[1].name
            const pw = roledata[1].password

            onLoginPage.userInput(username)
            onLoginPage.pwInput(pw)
        })
    
        onLoginPage.buttonEnter()
        cy.wait(500)
        cy.wait(500)

    // Navigate to page
        navigateGoTo.openTopNavi()
        navigateGoTo.visitWantedPage()

    // Get the value from a function of a different file
        let value = onPageWithTableCellObject.functionForSpecificTableCell_Month2()

        navigateGoTo.openTopNavi()
        navigateGoTo.wantedPage()

        // Insert the value from the function of the other file into an input field
        onWantedPage.Inputfiled2(toString(value))
    
    })
})
```

Result:

The test runs without any error messages (all green) but this remark and value shows up in the input field:

```
value in input field: [object Undefined]
```

With my research I did not get any results fitting to my example. Maybe my apporach is completely wrong?

I expected something like this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-return-statement/
Does not work for me. Any idea?
Thank you!